# BCP file insert command is not restoring the actual value of the Identity column

Tags: sql-server, bcp

BCP insert script is not restoring the Identity column values copied in the BCP file, instead SQL Server automatically assigns unique values based on the seed and increment values specified during the restoring process.

BCP format file creation -

```
BCP [SourceDatabase].[abc].[TableName] format nul -T -c -f Filename.fmt -S SourceSqlServer
```

BCP Data file creation -

```
BCP "EXEC [abc].[GetData]" queryout "C:\Filename.bcp" -S SourceSqlServer -d SourceDatabase -T **-E** -c
```

Restore data into the table -

```
BCP [abc].[TableName] in "C:\Filename.bcp" -f Filename.fmt -S SourceSqlServer -d SourceDatabase -T
```

I want to insert the values of the Identity column same as in the BCP file. Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add the -E switch by default bcp assigns new identity columns.

https://learn.microsoft.com/sr-latn-rs/sql/relational-databases/import-export/keep-identity-values-when-bulk-importing-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2014

Comment: Thanks you. So -E switch is required when we restore the data right?           BCP [abc].[TableName] in "C:\Filename.bcp" -f Filename.fmt -S SourceSqlServer -d SourceDatabase -T -E

Comment: I will check and let you know

Comment: @Thani Yes on restore

Comment: @Thani if this resolved your issue please mark the question as answered.